# Time Difference in SQL with Join

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I want to understand the relationship between a record being created in the `users` table and a user's first purchase in the `subscriptions` table. Both tables have `created_at` as a field, and `users.id=subscriptions.user_id`.

I'd like output that groups a count of users and the amount of time (in days) between the day that they joined and the day they made their first purchase.

```
days, users
0, 45
1, 63
2, 14
3, 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      days
    , COUNT(*) AS users
FROM
      ( SELECT
              DATEDIFF(MIN(s.created_at), u.created_at) AS days
        FROM 
              users AS u
          JOIN
              subscriptions  AS s
            ON
              s.user_id = u.id
        GROUP BY 
              u.id
      ) AS grp
GROUP BY 
      days
```